# Yggdrasil authentication with Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests, minecraft

I decided to try to make an automated login script for Minecraft. However, the new authentication API is stumping me. I can't find any mentions of the new functionality of the API on here. This is my code as it stands:

```
import requests
import json

data = json.dumps({"agent":{"name":"Minecraft","version":1},"username":"abcdef","password":"abcdef","clientToken":""})
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post('https://authserver.mojang.com', data=data, headers=headers)

print (r.text)
```

Unfortunately, this returns:

```
{"error":"Method Not Allowed","errorMessage":"The method specified in the request is not allowed for the resource identified by the request URI"}
```

According to [this](http://wiki.vg/Authentication) resource on request format, this error means that I didn't correctly send a post request. However, I clearly declared `requests.post()`, so my first question is how am I incorrect, and what is the correct way to go about this?

My second question is, since I'm relatively new to Python and JSON, how would I replace the username and password fields with my own data, inside a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified an endpoint in your POST request, for example:

```
https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate
```

The root of the website probably does not accept POST requests

http://wiki.vg/Authentication#Authenticate